# LINQ to Sql group and sum in subquery but account for null values

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql

I have the following query which works as expected until it reaches `null`values from the database.

```
var accounts = from p in db.PSR_FINAL_DATAs
            join c in db.PROJ_CUSTOMs on p.PROJ_ID equals c.PROJ_ID
            where !SqlMethods.Like(p.ACCT_ID, "%704-10-12%") &&
                    !SqlMethods.Like(p.ACCT_ID, "%-01%") &&
                    !SqlMethods.Like(p.ACCT_ID, "%706-10-12%") &&
                    SqlMethods.Like(p.PROJ_ID, "70000.%") &&
                    p.FY_CD == "2014"
            group p by new
            {
                p.ACCT_ID,
                p.PROJ_ID,
                c.PROJ_NAME
            }
                into s
                select new
                {
                    Project = s.Key.PROJ_ID,
                    Account = s.Key.ACCT_ID,
                    ProjectNumber = s.Key.PROJ_NAME,
                    July = s.Where(a => a.PD_NO == 1).Sum(b=> b.PTD_INCUR_AMT),
                    Aug = s.Where(a => a.PD_NO == 2).Sum(b => b.PTD_INCUR_AMT),
                    Sep = s.Where(a => a.PD_NO == 3).Sum(b => b.PTD_INCUR_AMT),
                    Oct = s.Where(a => a.PD_NO == 4).Sum(b => b.PTD_INCUR_AMT),
                    Nov = s.Where(a => a.PD_NO == 5).Sum(b => b.PTD_INCUR_AMT),
                    Dec = s.Where(a => a.PD_NO == 6).Sum(b => b.PTD_INCUR_AMT),
                    Jan = s.Where(a => a.PD_NO == 7).Sum(b => b.PTD_INCUR_AMT),
                    Feb = s.Where(a => a.PD_NO == 8).Sum(b => b.PTD_INCUR_AMT),
                    Mar = s.Where(a => a.PD_NO == 9).Sum(b => b.PTD_INCUR_AMT),
                    Apr = s.Where(a => a.PD_NO == 10).Sum(b => b.PTD_INCUR_AMT),
                    May = s.Where(a => a.PD_NO == 11).Sum(b => b.PTD_INCUR_AMT),
                    June = s.Where(a => a.PD_NO == 12).Sum(b => b.PTD_INCUR_AMT),
                    Total = string.Format("{0:C}", s.Sum(y => y.PTD_INCUR_AMT))
                };
```

How do I modify the query `s.Where(a => a.PD_NO == 1).Sum(b=> b.PTD_INCUR_AMT)` to account for null values?

EDIT:

I tried the following `s == null ? 0 : s.Where(a => a.PD_NO == 5).Sum(b => b.PTD_INCUR_AMT)` but this is the error message I receive:

```
The null value cannot be assigned to a member with type System.Decimal which is a non-   nullable value type.
```

Comment: First step is to find out *which* value is `null`. Then say so here.

Comment: The null value would be PTD_INCUR_AMT.

Comment: And what's the precise error message/symptom?

Comment: The null value cannot be assigned to a member with type System.Decimal which is a non-nullable value type.

Comment: It sounds like the database has a NULLABLE column, but the mapping is "NOT NULL". Verify that the type of `b.PTD_INCUR_AMT` *is* `decimal?`. If not, make it so! Also, make sure to put this information into the main post (update it as needed).

Comment: Would you please explain how to do that? I'm still very new to LINQ.

Comment: Hovering the pointer over `p.PTD_INCUR_AMT` in Visual Studio I believe it will say the the type (I use ReSharper which adds so much I have no idea what is standard and what is extra anymore!). If that doesn't work, check how `PRD_INCUR_AMT` is defined in the appropriate type (maybe F12 will navigate there?).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok just figured it out...this is the solution:

```
s.Where(a => a.PD_NO == 'whatever').Sum(b => (decimal?)b.PTD_INCUR_AMT)
```

Comment: In case anyone is looking, in my scenario I had a NVL on a subquery sum in my Oracle Query. Converting the property to nullable as psdpainter did produced a similar result as Oracle NVL did.